# TypeScript: Call overloaded asyncPipe with 0 or more arguments

Tags: typescript, functional-programming, typescript-typings

I have an `asyncPipe` function like this:

```
export function asyncPipe<A, B>(
  ab: (a: A) => MaybePromise<B>
): (a: MaybePromise<A>) => Promise<B>;
export function asyncPipe<A, B, C>(
  ab: (a: A) => MaybePromise<B>,
  bc: (b: B) => MaybePromise<C>
): (a: MaybePromise<A>) => Promise<C>;
export function asyncPipe<A, B, C, D>(
  ab: (a: A) => MaybePromise<B>,
  bc: (b: B) => MaybePromise<C>,
  cd: (c: C) => MaybePromise<D>
): (a: MaybePromise<A>) => Promise<D>;
export function asyncPipe<A, B, C, D, E>(
  ab: (a: A) => MaybePromise<B>,
  bc: (b: B) => MaybePromise<C>,
  cd: (c: C) => MaybePromise<D>,
  de: (d: D) => MaybePromise<E>
): (a: MaybePromise<A>) => Promise<E>;

export function asyncPipe(...fns: Function[]) {
  return (x: any) => fns.reduce(async (y, fn) => fn(await y), x);
}
```

I want to call it like this:

```
const createRoute = (...middleware: Middleware[]) => async (
  request: Response,
  response: Request
) => {
  try {
    await asyncPipe(...middleware)({
      request,
      response
    });
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
    response.status(500);
    response.json({
      error: "Internal Server Error"
    });
  }
};
```

where `Middleware` is a type for functions take in an object with at least the keys `request` and `response`, but might add more data the object.

```
{
  request,
  response,
  user, //  added by some middleware
  db, //  added by another middleware
  /* ... more keys added by middleware */
}
```

TypeScript complains and says `Expected 1-6 arguments, but got 0 or more.` in the line in which I call `asyncPipe`. How Can I tell it, that `middleWare` will always be at least one argument, or overload it, so it accepts 0 arguments, too?

**Update:**

I tried Rob's answer like this:

```
export function asyncPipe<A>(...fns: Function[]): MaybePromise<A>;
```

But that prevents all of my `asyncPipe` specific tests to fail. The tests btw, look like this:

```
import { describe } from "riteway";

import { asyncPipe } from "./asyncPipe";

const asyncInc = (n: number) => Promise.resolve(n + 1);
const inc = (n: number) => n + 1;

describe("asyncPipe()", async assert => {
  assert({
    given: "a promise",
    should: "pipe it",
    actual: await asyncPipe(asyncInc)(1),
    expected: 2
  });

  assert({
    given: "two promises",
    should: "pipe them",
    actual: await asyncPipe(asyncInc, asyncInc)(1),
    expected: 3
  });

  assert({
    given: "three promises",
    should: "pipe them",
    actual: await asyncPipe(asyncInc, asyncInc, asyncInc)(1),
    expected: 4
  });

  assert({
    given: "promises mixed with synchronous function",
    should: "pipe them",
    actual: await asyncPipe(asyncInc, inc, asyncInc)(1),
    expected: 4
  });

  {
    const throwInc = (n: number) => Promise.reject(n + 1);

    assert({
      given: "promises where one throws",
      should: "pipe them",
      actual: await asyncPipe(asyncInc, throwInc, asyncInc)(1).catch(x => x),
      expected: 3
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: I don't understand how changing the typescript definitions could cause working tests to fail. Underneath, you're always calling the same javascript code. Are you sure these tests were working before? (Or did you mean something else by "prevents my tests to fail?") You should always be able to write typescript as taking and returning `any`, and get the code working, and then apply types to constrain how the code is called. (I'm not saying that's the best way to write typescript, but it should always be possible.)

Comment: @RobNapier Sorry, I meant the code doesn't compile when I run my tests.

Comment: The signature you added is not the same as the signature of the implementation. I'm seeing "This overload signature is not compatible with its implementation signature." when I try to add that. Your other overloads return `(a: MaybePromise<A>) => Promise<B>`. Why does your new overload return `MaybePromise<A>`? The types need to match what you actually return.

Comment: That sort of strictly typed chaining was not possible in TS until recently, but Variadic Tuple Types should make it doable. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#variadic-tuple-types  I'll take a stab at it.  I am still getting used to some of the new features but this is a good challenge!

Comment: My progress so far: https://tsplay.dev/rNdkkw I've created a type that accurately creates the function chain based on the array of value types, but it's not able to infer the generic from the args. It only works if the generic is manually set.  So instead of mapping from the values to the functions, I have to try mapping from the functions to the values.

Comment: But it's hard to do that without getting errors about circular referencing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done some extra research and taken some of the answers here to make my own answer. You have two options now:

#### Option 1

One way of doing it is to just write the code of the `asyncPipe` function into the `createRoute` function:

```
const createRoute = (...middleware: Middleware[]) => async (
  request: Response,
  response: Request
) => {
  try {
    middleware.reduce(async (y, fn) => fn(await y), { request, response });
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
    response.status(500);
    response.json({
      error: "Internal Server Error"
    });
  }
};
```

This will definitely work, but I'm not sure if you have that type detection. Try the second option:

#### Option 2

The second way of doing it is a bit more complex. It will involve complex typings, but I think this is somehow what you want. (This code is taken from Arturs answer and modified)

```
type MaybePromise<T> = T | Promise<T>

export function asyncPipe<A, B>(
  ab: (a: A) => MaybePromise<B>
): (a: A) => Promise<B>;
export function asyncPipe<A, B, C>(
  ab: (a: A) => MaybePromise<B>,
  bc: (b: B) => MaybePromise<C>
): (a: A) => Promise<C>;
export function asyncPipe<A, B, C, D>(
  ab: (a: A) => MaybePromise<B>,
  bc: (b: B) => MaybePromise<C>,
  cd: (c: C) => MaybePromise<D>
): (a: A) => Promise<D>;
export function asyncPipe<A, B, C, D, E>(
  ab: (a: A) => MaybePromise<B>,
  bc: (b: B) => MaybePromise<C>,
  cd: (c: C) => MaybePromise<D>,
  de: (d: D) => MaybePromise<E>,
): (a: A) => Promise<E>;

export function asyncPipe<FS extends any[]>(...fns: AsyncParams<FS>): AsyncPipeReturnType<FS>
export function asyncPipe (...fns: AsyncParams<any[]>) {
  if (fns.length === 0) return () => Promise.resolve(null)
  return (x: Parameters<typeof fns[0]>[0]) => fns.reduce(async (y, fn) => fn(await y), x)
}

type Callback = (a: any) => MaybePromise<unknown>;
type FunToReturnType<F> = F extends Callback ? ReturnType<F> extends Promise<infer U> ? U : ReturnType<F> : never;
type EmptyPipe = (a: never) => Promise<never>

type AsyncPipeReturnType<FS extends Callback[], P = Parameters<FS[0]>[0]> = 
  FS extends [...infer _, infer Last] ? (a: P) => Promise<FunToReturnType<Last>> : EmptyPipe;

type AsyncParams<FS extends Callback[], P = Parameters<FS[0]>[0]> =
  FS extends [infer H, ...infer Rest] ?
    H extends (p: P) => unknown ?
      Rest extends Callback[] ?
        [H, ...AsyncParams<Rest, FunToReturnType<H>>] 
          : [{ error: "__A_PARAMETER_NOT_A_FUNCTION__" }, ...Rest]
            : [{ error: "__INCORRECT_FUNCTION__", provided: H, expected_parameter: P }, ...Rest]
              : FS;
```

You can try it out [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=44&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAsghiARhACgJwPYFsCWBnCAHgBUA+KAXimKgB8p1t8iyAoViADzAzWCgBmAVwB2AY2A4MIqHDwhxKHJEIBBADRQAQqQAUrKLMQAuKLrinVASkrl4SVJlwFCO1ldPnLNiuUbOiHQBuDm5efmFxSWlZeUVlIg1tTQBhPQMjTwsoa1tYBGR-ZldSdQzEMU8TbR87AscmFzT3LO88oqbSEK4ePkFRCSkZOQUxJRUkrVTNABF0wzhqrxza-IcOwNLyyrNqrVX7QqditLLDMQATTx2Ug-qNwjmWs2zc3wZjlznusL7IwZiI3iE00UygKVmmgAovNMi82u9Dg0AiUzlAKlVTPs8kiHqcMpdrqZbjj7p8iHM0RcIJ4rlAZnd1uTCDCyh54St2syYSFQr0IgNosM4mMEoQAGIAZSgXGAEBEFzwshEIAA2gBdPQAOh1AhEeEsIpQcDQcCweAlktI7NURoSACUIMAhGgRMRwEQpaQ+eF+lEhrFRuNoLodVq9QackaTWaLXAVRrrVAAN4ZHACMwRrUAG3lAHNgAALSgUKgABhsaCdLpkulWGy1VbwGGzADcILoREJs9mrBkq87XWZOKZjaasE6IGgLaBIBgMxHVWXNUv1ass1WLkIxB2gWIzCBNHr1yJzAB3OA4fggKyaTh9gC+7Fn0BScB7iDgYgA1pQOfGb1JJlGiIURvxEDAzxELpWBfKBxVEYgMEdQc3Q9CVyCocUZU4OUFSVN8Py-X8AH4oBQmt3RUcVyFleVFQ+EDCBwEQBCnKAAFVyDIjioFMCjXSoz1yFMEQIHbNAQjgqEsDAUBgz-ZYxIk+tmWUqdvVgj0oyDB1q0E9CpRwvCGMI7NPx-DVNBQP8xzNSdp0tVdSGcv8MiMuj8KgVUwxYti0CgAB9TQ-PYgAZORgHVKAyOWFBVKYhC3WQ-S0JUCK8GAUgRKgGS5JAYNeTg20gxjc1LWM+iCPfcziKshhbLKhyLSlZzXIodzpU8hjVVCgKAAlNF81j2MdTLopIjJDH6yqvN0MBR1WMCIKgmKpsMciIEy2bTJqizvw1NaNuO7zBqgMMSsUMqLTG4BNCSpCBLSoh+uy6L1pOvjvOTGU0EwNBTAAIkCwLVEClBVHtVQYChYgoXtQKADkAHliFBwLxQ4xGUmIABJZHEZBwGoAfIadVu9UPs+r7VR+qd-qBkHcex5H7XtKEcYxrGcfxwnAsBzQwEwVscGpOkzp6CAJAgC5ArAJq5QBhrSfO8mtqiqnqa+qVeSAA)

It is not possible to automatically infer the FS type.

If you want the next middleware of knowing about the previous one, you have to modify the type a bit and add it to the `createRoute` function.

Comment: Thanks, this is as close to an answer as it seems possible with TS right now.

Answer (score 1):

Add a "zero or more" definition. For example, you can expose your implementation's definition:

```
// Previous definitions
export function asyncPipe(...fns: Function[]);

export function asyncPipe(...fns: Function[]) {
  return (x: any) => fns.reduce(async (y, fn) => fn(await y), x);
}
```

Comment: This is good; I get the sense, though, that the original poster wants to limit the number of arguments to a specific number.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I amended my question because your answer didn't solve my problem.
@ShaunLuttin I don't want to limit it necessarily. But I have to overload for each new argument, because TypeScript otherwise can't handle function composition.

Comment: I'd say this is a non-answer. From the [_Do's and Dont's of TypeScript_](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/do-s-and-don-ts.html#any): Don’t use `any` as a type unless you are in the process of migrating a JavaScript project to TypeScript. The compiler effectively treats `any` as _“please turn off type checking for this thing”_. It is similar to putting an `@ts-ignore` comment around every usage of the variable.

Answer (score 1):

Explicitly typing `asyncPipe` like you tried offers best DX, as parameters of current step are inferred from the return type of the previous step. The downside of it is that only limited number of functions could be typed.

It is possible to type `asyncPipe` for an arbitrary number of functions - for example - with recursive types. But the downside of this approach is that types do not flow smoothly - parameters of the next function must be specified explicitly / manually to compile. As such it is not a problem if function to compose are already typed. If they are not, as a workaround to provide good ergonomics one could call `asyncPipe` in a nested manner and/or create some params builder taking one function at a time.

```
type MaybePromise<T> = T | Promise<T>

/*
  Handle empty arguments case - 
  return function which cannot be called:
*/
type EmptyPipe = (a: never) => Promise<never>
// export function asyncPipe(): EmptyPipe // -- not needed as cover by general case
export function asyncPipe<A, B>(
  ab: (a: A) => MaybePromise<B>
): (a: A) => Promise<B>; // asyncPipe should always return a function from a parameter of first function and Promise of return type of last function
export function asyncPipe<A, B, C>(
  ab: (a: A) => MaybePromise<B>,
  bc: (b: B) => MaybePromise<C>
): (a: A) => Promise<C>;
export function asyncPipe<A, B, C, D>(
  ab: (a: A) => MaybePromise<B>,
  bc: (b: B) => MaybePromise<C>,
  cd: (c: C) => MaybePromise<D>
): (a: A) => Promise<D>;
export function asyncPipe<A, B, C, D, E>(
  ab: (a: A) => MaybePromise<B>,
  bc: (b: B) => MaybePromise<C>,
  cd: (c: C) => MaybePromise<D>,
  de: (d: D) => MaybePromise<E>,
): (a: A) => Promise<E>;
// if needed please add overload for more functions like ef, fg etc.


// General case - arbitrary number of arguments
export function asyncPipe<FS extends any[]>(...fns: AsyncParams<FS>): AsyncPipeReturnType<FS>

// implemenation
export function asyncPipe (...fns: AsyncParams<any[]>) {
  if (fns.length === 0) return () => Promise.resolve(null)
  return (x: Parameters<typeof fns[0]>[0]) => fns.reduce(async (y, fn) => fn(await y), x)
}

// some auxiliary types
type Fun = (a: any) => MaybePromise<unknown>
type FunToReturnType<F> = F extends Fun ? ReturnType<F> extends Promise<infer U> ? U : ReturnType<F> : never

// this types assumes arguments are valid
type AsyncPipeReturnType<FS extends Fun[], P = Parameters<FS[0]>[0]> = 
  // P is parameter of first function; 
  FS extends [...infer _, infer Last] ? (a: P) => Promise<FunToReturnType<Last>> :
  EmptyPipe // no Last <=> length of FS is 0 

// recursively checks if list of function is compatible which each other 
type AsyncParams<FS extends Fun[], P = Parameters<FS[0]>[0]> =
  FS extends [infer H, ...infer Rest] ?
    H extends (p: P) => unknown ?
      Rest extends Fun[] ?
        // if current function and rest are okay, then pass current function, recurse with Rest and force next parameter based on current return type
        [H, ...AsyncParams<Rest, FunToReturnType<H>>] 
          // some hacks for pinning down exact issue and prevent compilation 
          : [{ error: "__A_PARAMETER_NOT_A_FUNCTION__" }, ...Rest]
            : [{ error: "__INCORRECT_FUNCTION__", provided: H, expected_parameter: P }, ...Rest]
              : FS // handles FS of length 0 and length 1;


const single = asyncPipe((a: string) => Promise.resolve(a.length)) // (a: string) => Promise<number>
const four = asyncPipe(
  (a: string) => Promise.resolve(a.length),
  (n) => [n, n],
  (c) => Promise.resolve(c[0]),
  aNumber => ({ aNumber })
) // (a: string) => Promise<{ aNumber: number }>

// general cases - parameters DO NOT inferred based on a return type of previous function
const zero = asyncPipe() // (a: never) => Promise<never>
const fiveAndMore = asyncPipe( // (a: string) => Promise<number>
  (a: string) => Promise.resolve(a.length),
  (n: number) => [n, n], 
  (c: number[]) => Promise.resolve(c[0]),
  (c: number) => `${c * c}`,
  // (c: boolean) => c -- ERROR
  (c: string) => c.length,
)

// workaround for letting the types flow
const nineWorkaround = asyncPipe( // (a: string) => Promise<number>
  four, // four async function already composed
  (x) => `${x.aNumber}`,
  asyncPipe(
      s => s.length,
      n => ({ aNumber: n })
    ),
  a => a.aNumber
)
```

[PLAYGROUND](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=90&pc=3#code/C4TwDgpgBAsghiARhACgJwPYFsCWBnCAHgBUA+KAXimKgB8p1t8iyAoVgegCpWooAJOADsAJgBtoELGFBQ4aAOYBXLBCHA8UAMZwCUALRReUNBGBK0QqADMlQrcBwYrAdwAWOLW+3ChGYFDIPmISIgBcrFwcrKCQUACi0qAoOHFUABRwYVBCEABuEGgAlJTkjLgEhLkFaKScHFAQAB5gGGgBtvaOznJ4IPYpkOlF2YkyIIPQHA36hn4BuRAiS73aGDWBIFAKaoVwYj4ErM2t7TZ2Dk5Wuv1ak4QAggA0UABCpOnGcIjZmdkPJQo5HgSFQmAqRHerBGUD+UABpQY4OYhHeAG4oNNerdJlA8G4MEoxCI5GIXAhNKZzJY5OculcbODaWB5HBVMBClAMNYbDg0HgOhdutdREimHpuSYzBYrLFoJKxLpBfTnMcWm1lZcejcBqkiM83i8AMIfL4-WFZeGA4EIZDlFHvJ7GRBaX7m17W2C2sHiogm6G-S0IoFiiGEE1otWnTXC7G6yCPF6vY0vAAipr430D-09ILtyMqjudrth7tz3vtlRNTr4WnCsJLRvLoMrRHTAYtOcRrcI6cjJw1dK11z68f1SZTUFTL3iGbk5rhwZtLYLkNINcCJfSZcReZ9Yerxjrv0bzfzvt76+My1+9dTZ-3KNnTphi89PdnkaxOB5i2WJLACRdGgOARBJdZCjEDBQJsNooCwNpoE6YdNDEHAAGtJGsF5rAURpgC0AA6dh6igABxXY0H2Q5oEMeREBwYAqLQLYhBUZA0C5Hl5GUVR1DwKNB2Q2MdTuPVCAAMQAZUaJoOVETRhBAABtABdD5CM06whDwf5RzuVksDwSSpNIGEHn0yYACVpUsYhwCIaS6lInBpAkPi4GFQSzmEhlRNxdJNMI7TdPhSzDOMpS1LMqAAG9jB-WEQsIiQhAUYBvAoLKoAABhKKkZVhd9V0I0w8AwMQCnSNiQiKYwCppdImmyFBDLMQpjLlSUQuUnL1N61TPWS0wRCULQIEyfTYRAHChCGoRMnJRioBAIoXiaOqAF92CxcrVDkJQmhwND5C2OUBLlKAJLsShOzkIRVt3CtV0IOx0L8FwhDqS7rqEYgMBs6k-ocyTyCoCTZPkkRNF+qAAH4oEBmV7ITCTyGaKHNB7HAhGsTkAFVyAR-GoGyJG7JBtHSZyfJCh2hoMvwKBzt6PAVAgRTFHZ-i5FMKA8n2HARBiBywpxPVyeB1GZIxtRoauuw1JeFBbtaqj2Q6kyBtIbXbuMLEVaZll1fazjur5AUh2FDFjGkyG5c0ZSgpxvHOIAfReF3OQAGSVVT4bulBiovX7-sllGiF9gVSHICI+DGZI9UxBo-CgKOAkIENUvS7xJTtpmcqMUjTC0Cw8BwAoxC2LwIC0dDNEStDLe6oUGSZrRsBZRxEAkKB3E8bwIDgLwuQyzkRbiCycQikz7YUhWhCVhhVbajl+S1vqdc3yhbZluSHagZSvc4-gXmd3HORsgV-bh4w+H4Of5fSMAWs9N6PqsW++G-xGOYCWX56-TUvDO+P9k5QESqXNAph1BWz8qKMqAR5DynQggF4Y8rAsjwJoKBMCYxXBeCXMu0AXCMW8FfJBoprBtHGjTOSUBjZslNoEYC4ErC4LUAEBqsoHKgJ-spU+UAgpTwGDPChLxQ4A1slLIg-AY7+z4WA3a2BoBuGHvXWCnEwA4yEDjPCIgMCfVksPAI+A2YgVFGAUwBRYEd2kMdTyDJFE-2yMpWKjRoFtGyAAIjdm7B4bsUAPCsg8GA8RiDxCsm7AAcgAeWIP4t2El8bRKNMQAAkrE6JfjvFQE2mfTSFDVLOLAa49xhRMBoB8X49JqTYlWSsvENJSSUlpMydkt23iXhWPWELJY2RBEnFrhyEQbtGEayqcvfJQjCl-2KWAhZ39sh2yxGo0QEgYYyQVGoHOuV7okmzhlKAABGSM7AO46QCOXNKvcqD+T1OkOEAo0B6ODhCUqHMKpVTgClHZGUiglCxE8pirzuwvTYlgDidQLmW2oRYW69yhjGGBS8tKbzmAfPKpVCaPzDluDWsiuaiJlJCBeEIVSG50haHRQQTFXyJpaAGgSzM0T2KchDOkdxcBWWQs5JtOqgKGgotBSGHsXKeUcWyBCjieTnJYh2LkKiBwdAEE0IYcZptNCpliVAOJNBj4jRYQQNhtJuHM1FpKKx+QnBKE0L5VUMKAgAC9CgYARZZB5gq7rVEKDSogPraisEdbyAoDxRAwEQu68WQxwHCrRWCi80rCh1D4HGhQfq6XYsyL8tK-zKVCClWy4oxLSU5ApUYVNJYk1oDUhmsq9KqVMspVWotnoAAGAASWKWgoBcG0JtNtG4gUlkQBgCqQ8iUhh7bMBIDT6nIpLM8kV5AiJ4pfPTPubRUGYDsCSahnEJDAEcGlZmbhoAs2sFBFwQbnCW10bkAA6lu+QhJRR3I9TGoFlol3xtFeCotKbYIWBeFiOFnFRJwO1GIUwoFq6dwwMa5FG1ESdtik0Qi3Ki0Do3IiiaijNAhjwDmnOG4f5WA5eKotUq8l1R-sy2kIYfmYd5WgaEUAgA)